# Flattened input layer shape

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, flatten

The code below was taken from TensorFlow in Practice by deeplearning.ai course in Coursera (computer vision example - week 2).

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

training_images  = training_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print("Executing Training:")
model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)
print("Executing inference:")
model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

The question: How TensorFlow deduce the shape of the input layer? Which shape is being flattened here? The input shape should be derived from the shape of the input data, Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the model.fit(training_images, training_labels), Tensorflow API automatically passes the training_images to the first layer.

Training_images is a tensor of shape (m, 28, 28, 1).
where,
m - Total number of training images,
28x28 - image size,
1 - channel (Gray scale),

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), reshapes the(28, 28, 1) 28x28 image into -> (784,).

View this for the Flatten() method source code. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L598-L684